# How to tab complete to a new snippet while already in a snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

If I'm already in a snippet and I press `tab`, I'll proceed to the next placeholder. However, if I'm already in a placeholder and I've typed a prefix that should trigger another snippet, if I press tab, I proceed to the next placeholder instead of expanding the prefix I just typed. Is there a way to expand the prefix I just typed within a snippet?

Here's an example:

```
    "test": {
        "prefix": "t",
        "body": "|${1}|${2}",
    },

    "text": {
        "prefix": "a",
        "body": "asdfghjkl",
    }
```

If I type `t` I'll get to: `||`
If I type `a` in the first placeholder and press tab I'll get: `|a|` where my cursor is at the ${2} placeholder
I would like to get: `|asdfghjkl|` instead

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that after you type `a` you have `|a|` and vscode will not recognize that `a` as a snippet prefix.  It looks like `|a` to vscode.  So if you actually made your second prefix to be `|` that would be recognized as the prefix, like:

```
"text": {
  "prefix": "|a",
  "body": "asdfghjkl",
}
```

You still have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to show suggestions and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the suggestion.  A <kbd>Tab</kbd> there would just go to the next tabstop

Alternatively, if you could insert a space like

```
"test4": {
  "prefix": "t",
  "body": "| ${1}|${2}",   // space added here
},
```

then you wouldn't have to modify the second snippet.

---

Also, make sure that you have

`Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions`

disabled (enabled is the default) so you can trigger the suggestions within the first snippet - but you have to manually trigger them yourself with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as mentioned above.